# Error while upgrading Angular version to the latest version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying upgrade angular version from 9 to 15. Following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0z_TH8agLk&list=PLYU1sQFiKADiBVEnDzTRGmcbHKrdtkD0o).
But I am getting error for angular dependencies. Please refer the screenshot I have attached below.

[image]

I tried following steps.

1. upgrade node by downloading and installing latest version of node
2. then upgrade the version of angular cli - `npm install -g @angular/cli` (globally and locally)
3. upgrade typescript

`npm install -g typescript`

> NOTE: The "@angular-devkit/schematics" package cannot be resolved
> from the workspace root directory. This may be due to an unsupported
> node modules structure. Please remove both the "node_modules"
> directory and the package lock file; and then reinstall. n be removed
> once the update is complete.

4. `npm install @angular-devkit/schematics`
5. Update the Core Packages & Dependencies

Expecting angular and its core dependencies to upgrade to latest version.

Comment: What error do you get. ? Did you try a `npm i --force` ?

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading your projects Angular version, consult the official guide [here](https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-15.0).

Selecting your current and desired Angular version, as well as other options on this site, will generate a step by step guide on how to update your project.

Answer (score 1):

`@angular-devkit/schematics` is not part of angular since at least version 13. Maybe just remove it from `package.json` when you do the upgrade.

That said, when you are skipping so many versions, you should first upgrade to version 10. Follow instructions [here](https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-15.0).